# Need to partition a SSD in Linux without elevated privileges

Tags: linux, partitioning, ssd

Pretty straight forward.  I am creating some software that needs to be able to remove existing partitions, partition and format an SSD/HDD without escalated privileges.  This can be done by just about any means necessary such as adding the user to a group, installing something akin to pmount (which we use for mounting drives without sudo), and/or ritualistic sacrifice to the elder gods.

I'm currently running centos 7.x on an Intel Xeon machine.  Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: The easiest way would then be to boot from a Linux LiveCD or USB and do the work there. You *need* admin rights to be able to do the work from within your current machine.

Comment: DOH!  I forgot a critical piece of info and shall revise my question to reflect this.  We're doing this programatically.  I've been up since four and was only half way though my coffee when I asked this.  My apologies.

Comment: It shouldn't be difficult to integrate a password request in your software so it runs with elevated privileges from then on. Giving such power to non-root users is a bad idea and can't be done, by design. You'd need to redesign and basically destroy a fundamental feature of the Linux security model.

Comment: Oh, I completely agree with you.  However, this is a very specific case on a system that will literally only exist for as long as it takes to run the software.  Sadly, for us, it really does have to be done as I've asked which has been a major headache.

Answer (score 0):

I concur with the boot from a Linux Live CD option. In fact a good method would be to make a live USB with GParted to solve all your partition needs. Grab the ISO from GParted and burn it to your flash drive.

Grab GParted here: https://gparted.org/livecd.php